# AngularJS: Can't use .then on promise from factory

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

With my current project i try to learn AngularJS + asp.net. I follow this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par?fid=1866174&df=10000&mpp=50&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=4928950).

My current code is:

**LoginFactory.js**

```
var LoginFactory = function($http, $q) {
    return function(emailAddress, password, rememberMe) {
        return $http.post(
            "/Account/Login", {
                Email: emailAddress,
                Password: password,
                RememberMe: rememberMe
            }
        );
    }
}    
LoginFactory.$inject = ["$http", "$q"];
```

**LoginController.js**

```
$scope.login = function () {
    LoginFactory($scope.loginForm.emailAddress, $scope.loginForm.password, $scope.loginForm.rememberMe)
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                if ($scope.loginForm.returnUrl !== undefined) {
                    $location.path("/");
                } else {
                    $location.path($scope.loginForm.returnUrl);
                }
            } else {
                $scope.loginForm.loginFailure = true;
            }
        });
    }
//CODE OMITTED
LoginController.$inject = ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$location", "LoginFactory"];
```

If i run this example i get an error in my browser console "**the object does not support the property or method 'then'**". As far as i understood the documentation of `$http` correct `$http.post` always returns a promise ? Why can't i use `.then` for it ?

If i rewrite my example like this (No use of LoginFactory):

```
$scope.login = function () {
    $http.post(
        "/Account/Login", {
            Email: $scope.loginForm.emailAddress,
            Password: $scope.loginForm.password,
            RememberMe: $scope.loginForm.rememberMe
        }
    )
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.success) {
            if ($scope.loginForm.returnUrl !== undefined) {
                $location.path("/");
            } else {
                $location.path($scope.loginForm.returnUrl);
            }
        } else {
            $scope.loginForm.loginFailure = true;
        }
    });
}
```

everything works fine and i get the results that i've expected. Why is the inline call successful but the factory call fails ?

Thanks for you help :)

---

**EDIT (In response to @NutBoltu):**
I've changed my main.js according to your suggestions

**main.js**

```
myApp.controller("LoginController",[ "LoginFactory", LoginFactory]);
myApp.factory("LoginFactory", ["$http", LoginFactory]);
```

Forthermore i changed my LoginFactory.js to:

**LoginFactory.js**

```
var LoginFactory = function($http) {
    return {
        http: function(emailAddress, password, rememberMe) {
            return $http.post(
                "/Account/Login", {
                    Email: emailAddress,
                    Password: password,
                    RememberMe: rememberMe
                });
        }
    }
}
LoginFactory.$inject = ["$http"];
```

But i still get the **"The object does not support the property or method 'http'"** error.

---

**EDIT2:** If i log the LoginFactory like this `console.log(LoginFactory);` in my Controller i get the folloing output (exactly the definition of LoginFactory):

```
function($http) {
    return {
        http: function(emailAddress, password, rememberMe) {
            return $http.post(
                "/Account/Login", {
                    Email: emailAddress,
                    Password: password,
                    RememberMe: rememberMe
                });
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution**
Thanks @NutBoltu for his help with this. The solution was to play the LoginFactory and the LoginController inline into the main.js. The solution is looking like this:

**main.js**

```
myApp.controller("LoginController", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "LoginFactory", function ($scope, $routeParams, loginFactory) {
    $scope.loginForm = {
        emailAddress: "",
        password: "",
        rememberMe: false,
        returnUrl: $routeParams.returnUrl
    };

    $scope.login = function () {
        console.log("controller ok");
        console.log(loginFactory);
        loginFactory($scope.loginForm.emailAddress, $scope.loginForm.password, $scope.loginForm.rememberMe)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.success) {
                if ($scope.loginForm.returnUrl !== undefined) {
                    $location.path("/");
                } else {
                    $location.path($scope.loginForm.returnUrl);
                }
            } else {
                $scope.loginForm.loginFailure = true;
            }
        });
    }
}]);

boundlessCommunity.factory("LoginFactory", [
    "$http", function($http) {
        return function(emailAddress, password, rememberMe) {
            console.log("factory ok");
            return $http.post(
                "/Account/Login", {
                    Email: emailAddress,
                    Password: password,
                    RememberMe: rememberMe
                });
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Angular factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) is a service provider which will be called to return the service instance. In your case, you are trying to return `$http.post` promise. You need to wrap the promise inside an object and return that object. Also you need to declare factory as below.

```
myModule.factory('LoginFactory',[ "$http", function($http) {
  return {
    http: function(emailAddress, password, rememberMe) {
        return $http.post(
            "/Account/Login", {
                Email: emailAddress,
                Password: password,
                RememberMe: rememberMe
            });
    }
  } 
]);
```

In your controller you need to inject LoginFactory.

```
myModule.controller('LoginController',[ "LoginFactory", function(LoginFactory) { 

    $scope.login = function () {
       LoginFactory.http($scope.loginForm.emailAddress, $scope.loginForm.password, 
                  $scope.loginForm.rememberMe).then(function(response{
                       //....
       }) 
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I've already tested this (this is the described solution in the mentioned tutorial) but it did not work (same error). I found a post about "defer anti-patterns" and there is no defer used too (that's my current appoach). 
http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you say `$http.post` returns a promise, and the original code was returning `$http.post`'s result, the original code was returning a promise. There should be no need for wrapper promises like in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I changed my set-up according to your suggestions. Unfortunately this does not work either. Now i get an **"The object does not support the property or method 'http'"** (thrown in LoginController)
Is it possible that my LoginFactory is not an "object" ?

Comment: @Alex do me a favor. Write console.log(LoginFactory); in your controller and tell me what it shows in the browser console.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your help :) I've updated my post.

Comment: @Alex my suggestion: Remove the var LoginFactory object from the LoginFactory.js and add that function in the factory as I did in my answer. It seems your controller takes LoginFactory as an object not a service instance.

Comment: Thansk :) This worked. I'll update my post with the solution and accapt your solution.